# Google Chrome not displaying Parallax images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I'm still a learning developer, and I'm not sure what the issue seems to be, but my Parallax images do not seem to load at all on Google Chrome only. Firefox, IE, and Safari seem to be working flawlessly. I've read about how it may have something to do with the fixed property due to a glitch in Chrome, but I'm unsure what my next step is.

So I have this current hero setup on many if not all of my pages:

```
<section class="hero-fullscreen parallax">            
        <div class="background-image">
            <img src="img/backgrounds/encounter.png" alt="img">
        </div>                         
    </section>
```

Below I have my CSS:

```css
.hero-fullscreen { 
    position: relative; 
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;  
    background-color: #0f1112; 

}
.parallax {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden
        
}
.parallax .container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}


.parallax > .background-image,
.parallax .slides li > .background-image {
  height: 100vh;
  top: -50vh;
  transition: opacity 0.9s ease;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.parallax:first-child .slides li > .background-image,
.parallax:first-child .background-image,
.hero-fullscreen.parallax .background-image {
  top: 0;
}
.main-container > a:first-child + .parallax .background-image {
  top: 0;
}
@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .parallax > .background-image,
  .parallax .slides li > .background-image {
    top: 0 !important;
    transform: none !important;
    -webkit-transform: none !important;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

 
/* Background Image */
.background-image {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-position: 50% 50% !important;
    z-index: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    background: #1c1c1c;
    transition: opacity .3s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .3s;
    
}
.background-image img {
    display: none
}
 
section {
    position: relative;
}
```

With my JS:

```js
 parallaxVossen();

    var isOpera, isFirefox, isSafari, isIE, isEdge, isChrome, isBlink, isMob;
    isOpera = (!!window.opr && !!opr.addons) || !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
    isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';
    isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
    isIE =  navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ");
    isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;
    isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;
    isBlink = (isChrome || isOpera) && !!window.CSS;
    isMob =  (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent));
    if (isChrome || isFirefox  || isSafari) {
        if ($(window).width() > 992) {
            $('.parallax').vossenParallax();
            
        };
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            function parallaxHero() {
                var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
                if ($(window).width() > 992) {
                    $('.map-parallax').css('top', -(scrolled * 0.4) + 'px');
                    $(".slide").css({transform: 'translate3d(0px, ' + (scrolled * 0.4) + 'px, 0px)'});
                }
            }
            parallaxHero();
        });
    }
    
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('.parallax-bg img').animate({opacity : 1}, 1000);
        $('.white-until-load').css({color : "#191a1c"});
        
    });
```

Like I said, it seems to be working on every browser except for Google Chrome.

Try for yourself: http://www.gracechurch.tv

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems to be working for me. See if you're Chrome settings are a factor (Chrome menu -> Settings -> Show Advanced Settings -> [Images Section] "Show all images")

Comment: The images not showing seem to only be parallax images.
Try going to http://www.gracechurch.tv/currentseries
In Chrome it is a grey screen, but in other browsers there is a graphic.

Comment: I'm seeing an error in the console *"Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'addEventListener' on 'EventTarget': The callback provided as parameter 2 is not an object."* - this is on the parallax plugin.

Comment: Also, it seems the video on the homepage will not play either, as if the problem is connected?

Answer (score 2):

Currently there are two fixes that I have found online that work.

You can add the following properties below to your element that contains a background image with fixed attachment.

```
yourdiv {
position:relative;
background-image:url(your_image);
background-size:cover;
background-position:center;
background-attachment:fixed;
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

OR you can change the position to static of the element with the background fixed image.

```
yourdiv {
position:static;
background-image:url(your_image);
background-size:cover;
background-position:center;
background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

Hope this helps for now.

Answer (score 0):

Its an issue with Chromes new update from 66 to 67. Check to see what Chrome version you are running. If it's 67, thats your problem... or should I say, Google's problem. I tested my site on version 66 on other CPUs and had no problems.

Comment: If you remove all the parallax lines from your CSS file, and make it a standard bg, your images will display again.

Comment: I'm currently on 66.0.3359.181 - which seems to be the version most people are on considering everyone seems to be encountering image issues.